# Нужно создать словарь с ключами от 1 до 10 и значениями number(1,10).Этот код создает пустой словарь!

Tags: python

```
a=0
data={}
while a<=10:
    data[a]:"number"+str(a)
    print(data)
    a+=1
```

Comment: Вам не помог ни один из ответов на ваши прошлые вопросы или вы сознательно игнорируете [правила ресурса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что значения ключам присваиваются не так

```
a = 1
data = {}
while a <= 10:
    data[a] = "number" + str(a)
    print(data)
    a+=1
```

А можно и короче

```
data = {n: 'number' + str(n) for n in range(1, 11)}
```